# Show div based on for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have select box and one table, in select box I have 1 to 5 numbers if I select 2 from select box the table should be show 2 times.

Here is my code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Lessons').change(function(){
     var lesNum = $('#Lessons').val();
     for(k=1;k<=lesNum;k++){
         $("#xyz").css("display", "block");
     }
});
});
</script>
```

and my table code is here:

```
<select id="Lessons" name="Lessons">
   <?php for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++):?>
       <option value="<?=$j?>"><?=$j?></option>
   <?php endfor;?>
</select>
<div id="xyz" style="display:none;">
 <table>
   //some table data goes here.
 </table>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hi Valentin, if i select 2 from select box i need table should be show 2 times and if 3 it show 3 times..i hope u got my point

Comment: _"i have ... one table, ... the table should be show 2 times"_ - What? Are you saying you want to make copies of the table? Your current JS code set the `display` property of the same element each time in the loop. Are there other elements not shown, or...?

Comment: yes i want to make copies of the table..

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now it's working as you want.

Comment: what happen if some choose 3 from dropdown and it shows 3 times table, but again same person select 2 from dropdown, then it should show 2 times ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can use:

**HTML**

```
<select id="Lessons" name="Lessons">
   <?php for($j=1; $j <= 5; $j++) {
        echo "<option value="$j">$j</option>";
        }
   ?> </select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = '<?php echo "<table></table>"; /* Generating the table */ ?>',
        parent = $('#result');
    $('#Lessons').change(function(){
        var lesNum = parseInt($('#Lessons').val(), 10);
        parent.empty();
        for(var k=1;k<=lesNum;k++){
            parent.append(table);
        }
    });
});​
```

I can recommend you to stay away from globals (`k` in the loop).
​
And a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pWLhS/5/

Comment: Hi Minko,,ur example is correct but in my table data so long i mean its more than 500 lines.so can i put that data in php file and continue the loop from java script

Comment: Ok, so just change the options and table generation to be dynamically.

Comment: Hi Minko could you please give me some example?

Comment: Hi Minko my table should be in html not from javascript..how can i do that..please help me out